# Iterate over json hash in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Json:

```
{
 "comments":[
    {"id":1,"author_name":null,"comment_text":null,"url":"http://localhost:3000/comments/1.json"},
    {"id":2,"author_name":null,"comment_text":null,"url":"http://localhost:3000/comments/2.json"},{"id":3,"author_name":"Yerassyl","comment_text":"Hello world!","url":"http://localhost:3000/comments/3.json"},
    {"id":4,"author_name":"Yerassyl","comment_text":"hi there","url":"http://localhost:3000/comments/4.json"}
 ]
}
```

How to iterate over each comment in comments. I want something like that:

```
//pseudocode
comments.each(key,value){
// do something
}
```

I tried map, but map is for arrays.

EDIT:
If i delete root node 'comments' i can use .map:

```
var commentNodes = this.props.comments.map(function(comment,index){
      });
```

Ignore this.props, it is actually React.js.
console.log(this.props.comments) returns my json objects with root node 'comments'

Comment: How do you try with `map`?

Comment: As per @suvroc - comments *is* an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have

```
var obj = {
 "comments":[
    {"id":1,"author_name":null,"comment_text":null,"url":"http://localhost:3000/comments/1.json"},
    {"id":2,"author_name":null,"comment_text":null,"url":"http://localhost:3000/comments/2.json"},{"id":3,"author_name":"Yerassyl","comment_text":"Hello world!","url":"http://localhost:3000/comments/3.json"},
    {"id":4,"author_name":"Yerassyl","comment_text":"hi there","url":"http://localhost:3000/comments/4.json"}
 ]
};
```

You can just do, for example,

```
obj.comments.map(function (comment) {
    console.log(comment);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already `JSON.parse`d the string, you can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate. [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is only for returning a new array from your existing values.

```
this.props.comments.comments.forEach(function(value, index) {
    console.log(value, index);
});
```

edit: Sounds like `this.props.comments` is the root object. Hence the accessor above

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to parse your JSON data:

```
var json = '{
 "comments":[
    {"id":1,"author_name":null,"comment_text":null,"url":"http://localhost:3000/comments/1.json"},
{"id":2,"author_name":null,"comment_text":null,"url":"http://localhost:3000/comments/2.json"},{"id":3,"author_name":"Yerassyl","comment_text":"Hello world!","url":"http://localhost:3000/comments/3.json"},
{"id":4,"author_name":"Yerassyl","comment_text":"hi there","url":"http://localhost:3000/comments/4.json"}
 ]
}';
var data = JSON.parse(json);
```

And then you can proceed and loop throught comments like this:

```
data.comments.forEach(function(comment, index) {
    console.log("Comments["+index+"]: "+comment);
});
```

**Note:**

Once your JSON is parsed you will get an object including an array of comments so you can easily use all the **[Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype)** methods with it including `forEach` and `map`.